# How to make a new file for each directory in another folder using bash?

Tags: bash, filesystems, command-line-interface

Say i have a file structure like so:

```
stuff/
  foo/
   foo1.txt
   foo2.txt
  bar/
   bar1.txt
other/
```

I'd like a bash command that finds all directories in the current directory in this case `stuff/` and creates files with the names of these directories in another directory, in this case `other/` with a desired extension eg. `.csv`.

The result would look like this:

```
stuff/
  foo/
   foo1.txt
   foo2.txt
  bar/
   bar1.txt
other/
  foo.csv
  bar.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit light on the "what did you try" front, but I'll indulge you.

To list all directories, we can use `find`:

```
$ cd stuff
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d
./bar
./foo
```

We can pipe this into a `while` loop which uses `read -r` to extract each successive directory name into a variable, here `dirname`:

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | while IFS="" read -r dirname; do echo $dirname; done
./bar
./foo
```

Finally, instead of `echo`ing the directory name, we can run `touch` to create the file with the desired name:

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | while IFS="" read -r dirname; do touch ../other/$dirname.csv; done
$ ls ../other
bar.csv  foo.csv
```

---

Alternative approach! Because there are many ways to skin a cat.

We can use `ls -d */` to list all directories:

```
$ ls -d */
bar/  foo/
```

Then we use `sed` to strip off the `/` and add the path and file extension:

```
$ ls -d */ | sed 's#\(.*\)/#../other/\1.csv#'
../other/bar.csv
../other/foo.csv
```

Then we use `xargs` to run a `touch` for each of these filenames:

```
$ ls -d */ | sed 's#\(.*\)/#../other/\1.csv#' | xargs touch
$ ls ../other
bar.csv  foo.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for your help i tried something similar to your find command but using cut. `find . -type d -exec 'cut -d "/" -f 2 <<< "{}"' \;` but i couldn't work it out this way. Also could you explain why there are escape characters around the capture group brackets in your sed command? i.e. `\(.*\)`

Comment: I think `-exec` just runs the command directly without going through the shell, so `<<<` wouldn't work (even if you quoted it correctly). The `\(` and `\)` are needed because `sed` uses annoying POSIX regular expression syntax, where `(` and `)` just match literal parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this：

```sh
#! /bin/bash

function read_and_cp() {
    for file in `ls $1`
    do
        if [ -d $1/${file} ]; then
            touch $2/${file}.csv
            read_and_cp $1/${file} $2
        fi
    done
}

read_and_cp stuff other
```